# Post hoc analysis for 3x2 cross tab analysis?

Tags: chi-squared-test, post-hoc, clinical-trials, isotonic

Apologies if this is straight forward. Also please note that I am using SPSS and don’t know how to use R/code. I’m a physician doing clinical research.

I’m doing an analysis regarding 3 different kinds of diseases (nominal categories) with a dichotomous nominal outcome (complication/no complication). I’ve setup a 3x2 analysis, demonstrated on the initial pass that there’s a difference. I suspect that group A<B<C in this complication, but worry that I used the wrong post hoc analysis to show this. I’ve read through many forums without much success. I learned about going back calculating adjusted residuals for each cell in the 3x2, and then I calculated p values for each cell, but I think that just tells me that this specific cell is different from the others in total, and not in specific for each pair wise comparison.

How do I go back and do the post hoc to test if A < B < C in this 3x2 analysis? After ive done the initial chi square analysis (almost Anova like, but not scale variables), I know that there is A difference. So at this point, why can’t I just do chi square between all the pair wise comparisons and use that as the post hoc (with bonferroni)? Again I’m not savvy in this, just trying to learn how to do it the right way.

Comment: The easiest approach (as per Lachin's *Biostatistical Methods*) is to do a Bon-Ferroni correction.  I'm not familiar with SPSS, but this could be done by hand or in excel if needed.  This would be my recommendation

Comment: You have an *order-restricted* alternative hypothesis, see [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00184-015-0544-x) or [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947398000358) or simply ordinal logistic regression (?). Don't know about spss, but you might need to find a local statistician.

Comment: Thank you. I will do the chi square + bonferroni to see. Thanks!